# Auto-linking bug on Stack Overflow when a URL has dashes?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

This URL isn't getting auto-linked like it should be:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model

Moreover, when used inline [like so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) or as a reference [like so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), it doesn't get auto-linked at all.

The above text uses:

```
Moreover, when used inline [like so][2] or as a reference [like so][test], it doesn't get auto-linked at all.

[test]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model
```

Comment: `<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model>` fails as well.

Comment: The work-around is to percent-escape the dashes: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%2Dattribute%2Dvalue_model`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works if you change the em-dashes to en-dashes.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

I don't know if this is a bug in Markdown, or if em-dashes are not supposed to be used in URLs at all. It's hard to find information via Google with all the style guides pontificating about em-dash vs. en-dash. (Apparently it's the "tabs vs. spaces" of typography.)

**Update:**

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), em-dashes are not reserved characters and are not in `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`, so they should be escaped when used in URLs.

Comment: Well, it might, and thanks for the temporary fix, but then we'd want to ask Google or Wikipedia to not serve the version with em-dashes. ;-) https://www.google.com/search?q=entity+attribute+value

Comment: On the other hand, [RFC 3987](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987) does allow them in IRIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the link: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)
with

> [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model)

i.e. `[Link text in square brackets](https://example.com/url-–with_dashes/)`

As outlined in https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#links

Comment: I believe the OP knows how to construct links in Markdown. The question was specifically about auto-links; that is, the behavior that occurs when you place a plain URL into Markdown text.

Comment: Do you know of any other way to make the links work with stackoverflows's current Markdown parser?

Comment: The other answer shows how -- click [edit] on that answer to see the Markdown source. Stack Overflow now uses CommonMark, so [there are several dozen ways to get links to work](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#links).