# Link cut off in post, but fully rendered in preview

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

I came across this link through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944936/ionic-reload-and-display-new-data-in-ng-repeat-when-clicking-back-button/31479119#31479119) (that I found via VLQ queue)

```
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html
```

In the post, only part of the link was turned into a link, and that cut off part of the link (everything past the hyphen in `Understanding-`).    As it happens, there was enough of the link to still work.  But in the edit screen, the preview showed the link rendered fully.

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html

What is the cause of this?  Some weird character set?  And it even did the same thing on this post (I just copy-pasted the link).  I'm using Chrome 43 on Windows 7.  I subscribed for the new nav, but I'm not sure it's related.

Screenshot of edit preview:

> [image]

Comment: maybe related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297800/allow-n-dashes-in-link-urls

Comment: So I guess the link cannot be free-form?

Comment: you can also do `[http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html)` which will work

Comment: @TinyGiant right but the free-form links won't work?

Comment: Not if they have certain special characters in them

Comment: Awesome, I think I'll edit the accepted answer of the link @NathanOliver provided and close my question as a duplicate.