# Link with round brackets looks good in preview, but broken after submitting

Tags: bug, status-deferred, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

The link [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nextprime((10%5E32)%5E2) looks fine in preview, but is broken after submitting the question or answer:

> [image: ok in preview]
>
> [image: broken after submit]

A workaround is to use the `[...][1]` syntax.

I don't think this is a duplicate of [allow n-dashes in link URLs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297800/allow-n-dashes-in-link-urls). This issue seems to be related to the round brackets.

Comment: Yes, it is the parentheses ("round brackets"). You can escape them with backslashes, and it renders fine after submission: `[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nextprime\(\(10%5E32\)%5E2)`

Comment: @CodyGray: thanks for confirming it. Of course I don't want to escape the braces. Especially if there is already a markdown parser that does a good job :-)

Comment: Nick A's answer shows that you're missing a closing parenthesis. If you add that the link works in the final version without escaping, but the preview will have a spurious trailing parenthesis. _This_ is the real bug here.

Comment: @CodyGray URL encoding them would be far better than escaping.

Comment: @jpmc26 `(` and `)` are allowed in URL, so "URL encoding" will leave them untouched, maybe you meant percent encoding, but I don't see how this would be "far better", since the problem here is not with the URL resolution, but with the markup syntax, escaping seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Kaiido Percent encoding and URL encoding are not distinct terms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. Parentheses are reserved characters according to [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2), so encoding them would be the better idea.

Comment: @jpmc26 I stand corrected, ecmascript's encodeURIComponent do not touch it though nor does FF address bar. But still the problem is with markup, not the url (and even the preview implementation of the markup sytax), so as a workaround for thos issue, escaping sounds correct.

Comment: @Kaiido I find escaping to be less practical as well, since it means that copying the link from the *source* of the markup will no longer work without manual modification. Both escaping and encoding require manual effort from the person creating the markup, but escaping requires no effort from people later trying to use it. Ideally, the bugs would be fixed, but when possible, I find it easier to just avoid using characters a language considers special in other ways. URL encoding lets you do that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket: `[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nextprime((10%5E32)%5E2))` results in: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nextprime((10%5E32)%5E2)).

Note the extra closing bracket at the end:

```
[...](...((10%5E32)%5E2)
vs
[...](...((10%5E32)%5E2))
```

Comment: So the question should be closed as a typo :P And the real bug is that the preview shows a spurious ending parenthesis in the above valid case.

Comment: In preview, an extra parenthesis [appears after the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLBzn.png) when using the correct number of parentheses. This is also a bug and would lead to users removing the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Question should definitely not be closed as a typo. Yes, he's missing a closing bracket, but it's still a bug that preview shows something different from actual result.

Comment: IMO it's still good practice to just percent-encode the URLs anyway. After all, what if you one day need to link a URL that contains *unbalanced* parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been resolved. However, I've updated to deferred vs completed since our team will be taking some time in the future to test and confirm that is indeed the case.